# Histogram with curve, representing histogram trend

Tags: python, histogram, curve-fitting

I have plotted histogram and now I want to have curve which will represent the histogram trend. I want my histogram binning to be logarithmic (as I have below in the code; Mass variable is predefined variable, ranging from 10^43-10^45 gram).

I have looked for many many codes but could not suit any of them to my case (tried to modify as well). Do you know how I can make this curve? Actually, I just want to modify my code in the way that it will also include plotting this curve above the histogram.

Thanks,

Salome

[See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaRdq.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=Mass
hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=10)
logbins = np.logspace(np.log10(bins[0]),np.log10(bins[-1]),len(bins))

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=Mass, bins=logbins, color='#0504aa', alpha=0.8, rwidth=0.85) 
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Mass $(g)$ ')
plt.ylabel('Number of halos')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What function is to be curve fit to the histogram, or will any visually correct-looking function work for your purpose?

Comment: I was thinking that there should exist the code which will itself fit the curve to the histogram, based on the data.  So probably any visually correct-looking function will work for my purpose. 
Thanks

Comment: In that case, I suggest trying a quadratic or cubic polynomial.